# PurgeCSS purged needed style for Bootstrap attribute

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5, vite, purgecss

In my Vite project I use Bootstrap 5.3 and PurgeCSS.

I tried this code to prevent to remove style for disabled button:

*vite.config.js*

```js
pluginPurgeCss({
            variables: true,
            safelist: ['btn-disabled', 'btn-disabled-color', 'btn-disabled-bg', 'disabled']
})
```

But I see that PurgeCSS remove styles for this button:

```html
<button class="btn btn-success btn-lg" id="submitButton" type="submit"  disabled>
```

May be because disabled is attribute?
Do you know how to prevent removing styles for disabled button?

---

I solve this problem by changing *vite.config.js*:

```js
 pluginPurgeCss({
        variables: false,
        safelist: [/^disabled/]
})
```

`variables: false` are strongly required. Or just remove this lines, because it false by default:

```js
 pluginPurgeCss()
```

And after this changes my button-success looks like I expected: green but some deemed color

**But issue is still open.**

**Is it possible to set `variables: true`  and tune safelist for looking same style for disabled button?**